# Accessing objects through their interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

What does it really mean? I am reading design pattern book. It says
**objects are accessed solely through their interfaces**, and I am not able to get my head around it, can some body give me an example (Will really appreciate if its in C#)

What do we really achieve by using it?

Thanks

Comment: Read this for your better understanding : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832280/why-we-do-create-object-instance-from-interface-instead-of-class

Comment: Design patterns are about functional requirements and how to translate that into a technical (standardized) implementation. What they basically mean (functionally) is that you separate implementation (technical: class) from the description (technical: contract / interface). Benefits of that? - read the link provided by Shoaib.

Comment: Thanks for Link @ShoaibRaza. atlaste, i don't think so the only benefits is multiple inheritance. Beside to that, we also achieve encapsulation and polymorphism, i hope i am right?

Comment: Yeah generalisation to be more precise. @Angloos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends. If the variable is of type "interface", then in that case the object can be accessed by the interface type only.

Let's consider an example - Suppose I have an interface as defined below -

```
interface IMyInterface
{
   string B();
}
```

and if I implement this interface using a class "MyClass" as shown below -

```
public class MyClass:IMyInterface
   {
      public string B()
      { 
           return "In Class";
      }
   }

   public class MyAnotherClass:IMyInterface
       {
          public string B()
          { 
               return "In Another Class";
          }
       }
```

and I create an instance of the class using the interface as shown below

```
   IMyInterface myinst = new MyClass();
```

then in the above case I can only get access to the Method B() using variable **myinst** which contains a reference to **MyClass** type.

Going further, let's say I have a method that takes a parameter of type IMyInterface as shown below -

```
    public class UseOfInterface{
    public void InterfaceUse(IMyInterface myPara)
    {
      myPara.B();
    }
}
```

and I call this method as shown below -

```
        IMyInterface myInst = new MyClass();
        IMyInterface myAnotherInst = new MyAnotherClass();

        UseOfInterface interfaceUse = new UseOfInterface();
        interfaceUse.InterfaceUse(myInst); // returns "In Class"
        interfaceUse.InterfaceUse(myAnotherInst); // returns "In Another Class"
```

Then, as shown above, it is decided at runtime as to which method is called using the Interface variable.

But if I had created a variable of type **MyClass** which would have contained a reference of type MyClass itself as shown below -

```
   MyClass myinst = new MyClass();
```

then method B() can be accessed using the MyClass instance. So it depends what type of scenario you are dealing with.

**Edit: Why Use Interfaces?**

The main reason to use an interface is that it provides a contract to the class for which it is being implemented apart from the multiple inheritance support in C#. Let's can see an example where the contract providing can be helpful.

Suppose you have a class - "Car" in your assembly that you want to expose publicly, the definition of the class is as shown below

```
namespace CarNameSpace
{
   public class Car()
   {
      public void Drive(IDriver driver)
      {
         if(driver.Age > 18)
         {
            driver.Drive();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

As shown above, anyone who implements the **IDriver** interface can drive the car, which is defined below,

```
interface IDriver
{
   string Age{get; set;}
   string Name {get set;}
   string Drive()
}
```

In turn to drive my car I would be exposing the IDriver interface to the outer world, so anyone who implements my interface can call the **Car's Drive**  method, doesn't matter how he drives the car as shown below

```
public class PerfectDriver:IDriver
{
   public PerfectDriver()
   {
     Name = "Vikram";
     Age = 30;
   }
   public int Age{get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Drive()
   {
      return "Drive's perfectly";
   }
}
```

The **Car** class can be used as shown below

```
  PerfectDriver perf = new PerfectDriver
  Car myCar = Car();  
  myCar.Driver(perf);
```

Comment: Thanks Vikram. It helped. Will it be possible if you can explain a bit why you would use it (Except the case that we can inherit a class from multiple interfaces)?

Comment: I think there is a typo here Vikram                                                     IMyInterface myInst = new MyClass();
IMyInterface myAnotherInst = new MyClass();  // you need to change  this class to refer to MyAnotherClass                               interfaceUse.InterfaceUse(myAnotherInst);                                          would not return the "In Another Class"

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class called `Espson` and it implements an interface called `IPrinter` then you can instantiate the object by it's interface.

```
IPrinter printer = new Espson();
```

Epson may have a number of methods that are not part of the `IPrinter` interface but you may not care.  All you may want to do is call a method defined in the `IPrinter` interface called `Print`

So then I can pass the class to a method called `PrintDocument(IPrinter printer)` and the method doesn't care what type of printer it is, it just knows it has a method called `Print`

Comment: Does it also mean, its giving us high level of Encapsulation and also polymorphism?

Comment: Yes and Yes but I wouldn't go overboard with it.  I don't agree that everything should be accessed by an interface instance but I do tend to favor that style of programming.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the *interface* has several meanings. In this case the author is talking that objects must be accessed through public methods (in C# through public properties also) only.

(Of course, inheritors may use protected methods).

Public methods/properties form the public interface of a class. It's not the same interface that described by `interface` keyword in C#.

Comment: Thanks Mark. The last statement is making things more abstract.

Comment: Does it also mean, its giving us high level of Encapsulation and also polymorphism?

Comment: @Angloos I don't think it's a high level of encapsulation. Rather it's just usual encapsulation.

Comment: Mark .. as much i work in this context, your's answer makes more and more sense

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a construct that describes the signature of the public members of an object.  It contains declarations (declarations only, no implementation) of properties, methods and events that are guaranteed to be present on any object that implements that interface.

Here's a simple interface and a few classes that implement it.  The interface "INamed" states simply that objects implementing the interface have a "Name" property that is a string.

```
public interface INamed{
    string Name{get;}
}

public class Person : INamed{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

public class Place : INamed{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

public class Thing : INamed{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

...And a simple method that accepts a parameter of that interface type.

```
static void PrintName(INamed namedObject){
    Console.WriteLine(namedObject.Name);
}
```

This "PrintName" method can accept a parameter of any type that implements that interface.  The advantage of "accessing objects by their interface" is that it infuses your application with a certain flexibility, accessing these interfaces as opposed to their concrete types allows you to operate on these objects without having to know what they really are.

I could, for instance choose to operate on the IDbCommand interface as opposed to a concrete SqlCommand and much of what I write in this manner will be useful when working with a variety of database providers.

The simple idea is that you don't need to know if you're in a car or a boat because you can drive anything with a wheel and pedals.

Comment: Thanks Mik3c. I agree it does have the concept of BlackBox. By BlackBox i mean user really doesn't know about what these objects are

Answer (score 0):

The interface refers to what the object exposes to users of the object.  An object will be an instance of a class which will have its own interface and possibly implement one or more other interfaces.

While languages such as C# allow you to define things called interfaces, those are distinct from the interface referred to in the statement that objects are accessed through their interfaces.  In a language such as Scala, for instance, what C# calls an interface is called a trait.  Most design patterns do involve the use of defined interfaces, i.e. `public interface <interface name>`, but again, those are distinct from what is meant in the original statement.

Suppose I define the following class in C#:

```csharp
public class MyType
{
  public void Method1()
  {
    ...
  }

  private void Method2()
  {
    ...
  }

  public int Method3()
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then the interface through which I interact with the class is the two methods it exposes, `void Method1` and `int Method2` and the implicit parameterless constructor.

Now, suppose I define the following interfaces and class:

```csharp
public interface IInterface1
{
    void Method1();
}

public interface IInterface2
{
    int Method3();
}

public class MyType2 : IInterface1, IInterface2
{
  public void Method1()
  {
    ...
  }

  private void ADifferentMethod()
  {
    ...
  }

  public int Method3()
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

The interface through which a user interacts with instances of `MyType2` is the same as that through which a user interacts with instances of `MyType1` (except for the different constructors) because the signatures of the public methods (and other public members) are identical : `void Method1` and `int Method3`.