# How to convert class with generic type to class with object as generic type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

Hello I'm using Visual Studio 2005 (because I need compact framework support) and my problem is with generics.

I have created an abstract class called AbstractDAO which is my base

From that I am creating other classes like DocumentDAO,HeaderDAO etc which represent different tables on my database

What I wish to do is retrieve a certain number of the above mentioned DAO classes, but as an AbstractDAO (the abstract class has a number of concrete implementations that I wish to use)

What I tried is

```
AbstractDAO<object> dao = new DocumentDAO();
AbstractDAO<object> dao = (AbstractDAO<object>)new DocumentDAO();
AbstractDAO<T> dao = new DocumentDAO();
```

I need the above because I have created a function that transfers data from one table to another similar table in a different database, so it would (if it worked) go something like this

```
AbstractDAO<object> dao_local = new DocumentDAO(local_database);
AbstractDAO<object> dao_remote = new DocumentDAO(remote_database);      
do_transfer(dao_local,dao_remote)

void do_transfer(AbstractDAO<object> from, AbstractDAO<object> to) {
     List<object> items = from.get_all();
     to.insert(items);
}
```

Is there any way to do the above?

Comment: Dude - how do You excepct to be able to assign a value of type B to a variable of type A (at least that's what Your first line does..)

Comment: This is like c# basics : AbstractDOA doa = new DocumentDOA(); or

Comment: This will only work if you class hierachy is like:

Comment: because B is an implementation/subclass of A. 


using AbstractDOA doa = new DocumentDOA() throws an exception saying 
Using the generic type 'AbstractDAO<T>' requires '1' type arguments

btw what you said does indeed work in Java , but it seems that it does not work in c#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766794/how-to-create-generic-data-access-object-dao-crud-methods-with-linq-to-sql

Comment: yes my problem is similar (without the LINQ) only imagine if I tried to cast (in that example) CustomerRepository to a variable of type Repository<T>

Comment: Did you try [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)? This framework can map similar objects (objects with similar field names) without configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the answer to what I was trying to do, instead of assigning abstractDAO to something I created a factory that would retrieve the required AbstractDAO according to what type the generic was, and used this function

```
private bool transfer<T>(){
    AbstractDAO<T> local = DAOFactory.get<T>(local_database);
    AbstractDAO<T> remote = DAOFactory.get<T>(remote_database);
    List<T> items = local.get_all();
    foreach (T item in items) {
        remote.insert(item);
    } 
}
```

That way I can call this function like this:
    transfer< Document >();
    transfer< Header >();

etc. and do a full transfer

edit: just for completeness' shake this is the factory I created

```
    public static AbstractDAO<T> get<T>(Database database) {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        if (t == typeof(Document)) {
            return new DocumentDAO(database) as AbstractDAO<T>;
        } else if (t == typeof(Header)) {
            return new HeaderDAO(database) as AbstractDAO<T>;
        } etc.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That will only work if your class hierachy is like this:

```
class DocumentDAO : AbstractDAO<object> {
    //...
}
```

By your comment it seems like you have a type hierarchy like this:

```
class DocumentDAO : AbstractDAO<SomeType> {
    public override SomeType Foo() {
        //...
        return someValue;
    }
    //...
}
class AbstractDAO<T> {
    public abstract T Foo();
    //...
}
```

You probably want to refactor AbstractDAO to implement a non generic interface like IAbstractDAO:

```
class IAbstractDAO {
    object Foo();
    //...
}

class AbstractDAO<T> {
    public object Foo() {
        return Foo();
    }
    public abstract T Foo();
    //...
}
```

Comment: My hierarchy is like the one you posted last (without the interface)
`class AbstractDAO<T> { }
class DocumentDAO : AbstractDAO<Document> {}`

But adding this:
`        public List<object> get_objects() {
            List<T> items = get_all();
            return items as List<object>;
        }

        public int insert_object(object obj) {
            return insert((T)obj);
        }`

in abstract dao seems to not throw errors so I guess I can use that, it's not exactly what I wanted (i.e. being able to cast the subclass to the superclass) but I can work with that , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Any implementation of `AbstractDAO<T>` is compiled to a separate object type where T is replaced with the type. See "[Is generics runtime or compile time polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708090/is-generics-runtime-or-compile-time-polymorphism)" for more information on how this happens. In short, don't let the `<T>` fool you.

This means that you can't assign `DocumentDAO` to `AbstractDAO<object>` any more than you can assign String to it. Also a generic type is not the same as inheriting, which seems to be what you are trying to achieve.

In either case there are two standard solutions, as already mentioned.

The first is to [operate on interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832280/why-we-do-create-object-instance-from-interface-instead-of-class). You create an interface for the common properties and have `AbstractDAO<T>` or any other inherit from this. Then most of the time you simply operate on interfaces. Exactly how you organize it is up to you.

The second is to perform a [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18066487/313088) of the object. This means copying values and references from one object to the other. For this you usually use an object mapper like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). [This tutorial](http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-getting-started/) should get you started..

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot, I went with another solution, I will post it below, but the literature certainly helped me understand the workings of generics better

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) to transfer your objects like this:

```
void do_transfer(AbstractDAO<FirstType> from, AbstractDAO<SecondType> to) 
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg=>cfg.CreateMap<FirstType, SecondType>);

    List<FirstType> fromItems = from.get_all();
    List<SecondType> itemsToInsert = 
        Mapper.Map<List<FirstType>, List<SecondType>>(fromItems);
    to.insert(itemsToInsert);
}
```

By default automapper will map fields with same names. You can create [configurations](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration) for complex type mapping.

Comment: my problem isn't that I can't convert the type of from to to, my problem is that i want to have a generic as an argument to that function if possible
I.e. either `do_transfer(AbstractDAO<T> from, AbstractDAO<T> to)` or 
`do_transfer(AbstractDAO<object> from, AbstractDAO<object> to)`

the thing is that I can't seem to cast AbstractDAO<T> to AbstractDAO<object> even though in theory object is the superclass of all objects

Comment: Did you try to declare transfer like this `DoTransfer<TSource,TDest>(Dao<TSource> source, Dao<TDest> dest)` ?